# causitive or not?

Tags: grammar

There is a message on telegram

> "All your Telegram contacts ***will get your new number added*** to their address book, provided they had your old number and you haven't blocked them in Telegram"

Is this causitive or in the meaning of "will add your number"?

If the meaning is "will add your number", what is the purpose of meaning it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  construction underscores the automatic nature of the transaction.

Something that will *happen to* the Telegram contacts (they are the passive recipients) is being expressed in a manner that puts the acted-upon  in the role of subject.  They will have it happen to them. They will have the number added to their address books. They are not causing it to happen.  If you have not blocked them, and if they have your old number, your new number will be placed in their address books.

Comment: Your comment has a sentence.

''They will have it happen to them''

is not  that sentence supposed to be:
''They will have it happened to them''
I have some confusion about that kind of grammer phrases.

Comment: They will **have it** + INFINITIVE (happen), not past participle.   They are not *causing* it to happen to themselves as they are when they *have the house **painted***.  These are not the same construction.   In the former they are passive recipients or sufferers of the action; in the latter they are the causative agent of the action.

Comment: He had his face slapped. He had his car washed.  He got his face slapped.  He got his car washed.

Comment: I have 2 questions about your last comment

1) Can I make this structure ''get it +INFINITIVE'' instead of 
''have it+INFINITIVE(happen)''
Ex: ''They will **get** it happen to them''


2)''He had his face slapped'
in this sentence he did not cause someone to slap his face.
he did not intend it or he did not pay someone to slap his face
sentence is different to they have the house painted.
because they intended it. may be they paid someone else to paint the house.
so is not first structure more suitable for this sentence?

''he had his face slap''
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are suggesting forms of the verb which are not allowed.  He had his face **slapped**, not **slap**.  They will get it **to happen** to them, not  **happen**.  They can *make* it **happen** to them.